# Python wait for request to be processed by queue and continue processing based on response

Tags: python, multithreading, queue

I have the following setup:

1. One thread which runs a directory crawler and parses documents
2. Another thread which processes database requests it gets in a queue - there are two basic database requests that come through - mark document processed (write operation) and is document already
   processed (select operation)

I understand that an sqlite connection object cannot be shared across threads, so the connection is maintained in the database thread. I am new to threading though and in my parser thread I want to check first if a document has been processed which means a database call, but obviously cannot do this call directly and have to send the request to the database thread which is fine.

However, where I am stuck is I am not sure how to make the parser thread wait for the result of the "has document been processed" request in the database thread. Is this where a threading event would come in?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: ***"I understand that an sqlite connection object cannot be shared across threads"***: Have you any reference about this? My experience is: **a cursor object cannot be shared**.

Comment: You are right, the cursor cannot be shared but for efficieny I went for a singleton design for my database so to remove the overhead of always having to build up a connection. So my singleton pattern always returns the cursor when it is called, which is why I cannot call if from different threads.

Comment: ***"his where a threading event would come in?"***: Read up on [threading.Event.wait](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Event.wait), should do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to stovfl, used a threading event to realise this. Thanks again!